# Proof that Parallel Universes exist

Tags: black-hole

Today I heard on the radio that the Super Collider has discovered mini black holes. They said that this discovery is proof of the existence of Parallel Universes and that the "Big Bang" never happened.I don't understand this and why this discovery means that Parallel Universe exist ? Does anyone know ?

Comment: "Super Collider" - Which particle collider/accelerator/detector are you referring to? Also, how could mini black holes prove the existence of parallel universes or disprove the Big Bang theory?

Comment: I believe he was referring to an experiment conducted over the weekend at CERN. Though it may be better to limit interpretations of the results to scientists rather than media reports. This may also be more fitting for physics.

Comment: I don't have much of an answer for you, but here is a source of information that most people seem to be referencing. In the end it seems that the media is trying to make money, as usual, by making a bigger deal out of something than it should be.
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370269315001562

Comment: @HDE 226868 I just reported what I heard on the radio so it would take a Scientist to be able to answer your questions.

Comment: This is one of the biggest discoveries ever made ,that Parallel Universes exist and that the "Big Bang" never happened and it gets down voted because the person cannot comprehend the meaning of this discovery ?

Comment: @PeterU All I'm asking for is where this took place. It doesn't take a scientist to answer this. I also suspect that the extrapolations are waaaay overplaying the whole thing, but I can't know that until I figure out where the source is. Which is why I'm asking you.

Comment: @HDE 226868 It took place where the supercollider is. Mitch Goshorn says that it was at CERN

Comment: Superconducting **supercollider** was *the* big US accelerator project for the new millenium, until it was cancelled in 1993. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconducting_Super_Collider Originally designed to be 5 times more powerful than Europe's current LHC, the project is now just a large, expensive hole in the ground in Texas. Journalists like the term "supercollider", so you still hear it used.

Comment: "Parallel universe" can have a variety of definitions... Other instances of big bangs are necessary for existence of a parallel universes. We currently have only indications of of one big bang event. It is absurd to suggest that the creation of very improbably self aware entities such as humans, can occur frequently on all planets, it requires many planets. It's very Improbable that a dimensional state capable of stable matter and atomic stasis is possible without the existence of many universes.

Answer (score 3):

Your radio information source is wrong.
The Large Hadron Collider has **not** discovered mini black holes.
When it comes back on line this spring, the LHC will begin looking for mini black holes: [Large Hadron Collider Could Prove the Existence of Star Trek's Parallel Universe](http://www.sciencetimes.com/articles/4928/20150327/large-hadron-collider-prove-existence-star-treks-parallel-universe.htm)

Journalists *do* like their headlines, but the gist is this:

> When the Large Hadron Collider is brought back online in the spring, researchers will be looking for the existence of mini black holes. These mini black holes would lend support to string theory, which posits that different dimensions and parallel universes are possible.

No miniholes yet, maybe never.

Comment: Yes, but why would the discovery of "Mini Black Holes" mean that Parallel Universes exist and bring into doubt the "Big Bang" theory ?  Actually this theory makes more sense to me because with the Big Bang theory ,I could never understand how all the matter in the Universe, could start out in something the size of a grapefruit ? Also how would they determine that a Mini black Hole has formed, it can't be seen , so what gives it away ?

Answer (score 0):

In 2007, Nobel laureate Steven Weinberg suggested that if the multiverse existed, "the hope of finding a rational explanation for the precise values of quark masses and other constants of the standard model that we observe in our Big Bang is doomed, for their values would be an accident of the particular part of the multiverse in which we live.

Comment: The ultimate irony-- the concept of parallel universes is a product of rationalism, the idea that what exists is what makes sense to us to say exists, rather than what we observe to exist (one does not observe parallel universes).  Yet the concept also kills the highest dream of the rationalist: an explanation of how things are based on how they "had to be."  A rationalist dream killed by a rationalist construction!   The universe is how we find it because otherwise it wouldn't be how we find it.